# Inno Setup will not create folder under C:\Users\Public - will instead do C:\Users\Public\Public Documents

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to build my installer and I have the `C:\Users\Public` folder hardcoded in my `[Files]` section to place some files (Inno Setup does not have a constant for this folder)

My goal is to have the install create a `C:\Users\Public\MyApp` folder with some files in it. However when I run the install, it is creating the folder here:
`C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\MyApp`

Is this a permissions issue where the installer doesn't have access to create a folder directly under `C:\Users\Public`?

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp\db.mdf"; DestDir: "{drive:{src}}\Users\Public\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Try suggestions in my answer. And if it does not help, show us a log file. + What version of Windows are you testing this on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. For me your code works. I've tested it on Windows Vista, 7 and 10. It always installs to `C:\Users\Public\MyApp`.

---

Though I do not understand the `{drive:{src}}`. How does the drive of the `Users` folder relate to the drive of the installer? You should use the [`{sd}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=sd):

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp\db.mdf"; DestDir: "{sd}\Users\Public\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

---

But anyway, to resolve the path to the `C:\Users\Public`, you can use the `PUBLIC` environment variable:

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp\db.mdf"; DestDir: "{%PUBLIC}\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

It works since Windows Vista.

Alternatively, you can use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) with `FOLDERID_Public`. For an example code, see [Constant for AppData\LocalLow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35219952/850848)

---

If you need to support even Windows XP, where there is no `C:\Users\Public` folder or `PUBLIC` variable, you have to find out, what path your need to use there instead (probably `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users`), and implement a fallback using a scripted constant:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{code:GetPublicPath}\MyApp"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]

function GetPublicPath(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := GetEnv('PUBLIC');
  if Result <> '' then
  begin
    Log(Format('PUBLIC is "%s"', [Result]));
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := GetEnv('ALLUSERSPROFILE');
    Log(Format('PUBLIC is not set, ALLUSERSPROFILE is "%s"', [Result]));
  end;
end;
```

---

And for others, it's worth noting that your need for resolve `C:\Users\Public` is very specific, related to this question: [C++ app MDB in ProgramData copies to user's AppData folder when I dont want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43307877/850848).

One usually does not want the `C:\Users\Public`, but `C:\Users\Public\Documents` (= [`{commondocs}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commondocs)) or `C:\ProgramData` aka `C:\Users\All Users` (= [`{commonappdata}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commonappdata)).

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I however am not. I made a very simple Inno Setup file to test and you are correct... it maps correctly to C:\Users\Public. Looking at my original Inno file, I found my mistake. I had a Check parameter which would run one command for XP and another for more recent O/S. Well I had that Check command switched between the two so it was calling my XP code on my Windows 10 system (trying to put it at     C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents    )

Comment: As for your comment "One usually does not want the C:\Users\Public"... why is the reasoning behind that? Are you saying I should be putting my mdb under the C:\Users\Public\Public Documents folder?

Comment: Shared user-visible documents should go to `C:\Users\Public\Public Documents`. Shared private application data should go to `C:\ProgramData` - I've understood that you have to deploy your files to `C:\Users\Public`, because you have no control over the location.